# Rails, How to replace or write data in excel sheet file using 'roo' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to replace one column of data to another column of row in cell using 'roo' gem.
I have compared two columns data, and want to replace second column of row by first column of row data.

Comment: I don't believe `roo` provides write access to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem description says

> Roo implements read access for all common spreadsheet types

so you most likely need a different gem to complete your task.